# How to check if a node in k8s cluster got rebooted

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm, microk8s

k8s master checks for kubelet status at frequent intervals. Maybe we can change that time and that makes the node not-ready. But that doesn't always mean that the node got rebooted.

1. How to change kubelet status check frequency?
2. If I don't want to change the kubelet status check frequency, then how could I get to know whether a node got rebooted?

Answer (score 0):

As per the [official Kubernetes documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kubelet/) the frequency can be changed using the `--node-status-update-frequency duration` flag, but please see the limitations. To check node condition you can reference to [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/architecture/nodes/#condition), if you want to check strictly node uptime you please see [this](https://rootsquash.com/check-uptime-for-kubernetes-nodes/).

Comment: Hello @user762025 and welcome to ServerFault! Please remember to [react to answers for your questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). 
That way we know if the answers were helpful and other community members could also benefit from them. Try to [accept answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) that is the final solution for your issue, upvote answers that are helpful and comment on those which could be improved or require additional attention. Enjoy your stay!